# How can I enable filtering and sorting using Sieve in a one to many object relation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sorting, filtering, sieve.net

The documentation for https://github.com/Biarity/Sieve#nested-objects does mention nested objects, but this only seems to apply to 1:1 relations. In my situation I have a 1:N relation, for example a Author object, containing a list of Books.

I want to enable sorting and filtering on properties of the Book object, for example Title.

As stated in the documentation, this cannot be done using attributes. Instead the fluent API should be used, but there is no example of how to get this working.

I've tried for example this configuration:

```
public class AuthorSieveConfiguration : ISieveConfiguration
{
    public void Configure(SievePropertyMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.Property<Author>(dto => dto.Books);
        mapper.Property<Book>(dto => dto.Title).CanSort();
    }
}
```

but this has no effect.